# How to convert returned array to dictionary with Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, facebook, dictionary

I'm using FB API to get the list of user's page likes. But i'm stuck with converting array (the array is the return data from FB API) to dictionary.

My code:

```
let params = ["fields": "about,name,created_time,picture", "limit": "3"]
    Facebook.getUserPagesLikes(params: params, handler: { (userData) in
        guard let pagesArrays = userData["data"] as? Array<Any> else {return}
        print("page array: \(pagesArrays)")
    }) { (error) in
        print("cannot get FB pages: \(String(describing: error))")
    }
```

Return Data:

```
 [{
    about = "This is the OFFICIAL facebook page for the Linus Tech Tips and TechQuickie YouTube channels. Run by our entire team. (Note: PMs are not read, use Twitter)";
    "created_time" = "2017-08-03T04:23:08+0000";
    id = 343018322461286;
    name = LinusTech;
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/17021592_1241602709269505_8744271496063654606_n.jpg?oh=6b34199b5753bc64def8474713c3ae6c&oe=59F1F116";
        };
    };
}, {
    about = "Wilaime.contact@gmail.com\nInstagram : @wilaime\nTwitter : @WilAime\nSnapchat : wil.aime";
    "created_time" = "2017-07-05T13:41:50+0000";
    id = 666964646732880;
    name = "Wil Aime";
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/1964962_757890660973611_6828038531185039189_n.jpg?oh=f877b27948e68ea63dd95905a4f5642a&oe=5A2C75FD";
        };
    };
}]
```

Please help me to convert this array to dictionary so that I can access the name,about etc value. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show response from FB?

Comment: this is response from FB https://pastebin.com/fYaKWMAb

Comment: Can you add in what structure you require the dict, like if you convert the array to dict, what would be the key for each element in that dict, etc..

Comment: All you have to do is change this line: `guard let pagesArrays = userData["data"] as? Array<Any> else {return}` to this `guard let pagesArrays = userData["data"] as? [[String:Any]] else {return}`. Namely, you cast the response to an array of dictionaries rather than a simple array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get dictionary value like.

```
for dic in pagesArrays{
    let dicOne = dic as! NSDictionary
    print(dicOne[about]!)
    print[dicOne[name]!]
}
```